# Docker installation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, docker

I'm trying to install Docker on my workstation Ubuntu 14.04 LTS following : https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

When I do :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

It says "linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic" is already up do date, but when I do :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

It says (sorry it's in french) :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 linux-image-extra-virtual : Dépend: linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.24.28) mais 3.13.0.39.46 devra être installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

Google translator gives :

```
The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-virtual: Depends on: linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.24.28) but will need to be installed 3.13.0.39.46
E: Unable to correct problems, defective packages are in "keep as is" mode.
```

EDIT 2 : the real error message is :

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

which means if I understand linux-image-generic is not the version expected but can't be upgraded since it's in "keep as it is" mode.

What can I do to install Docker from there ?

EDIT : before installation, I've done :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The french message is just wrong, it's not "but 3.13.0.39.46 will have to be installed", it's "but 3.13.0.39.46 IS installed", so it was requesting for a downgrade.

When u do the same with aptitude, u get the right message, and it proposes you to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar but not the same error just now when I tried to install docker on my Ubuntu 14.04 with "4.4.0-75-generic" kernel version.

The error info is:

> Setting up linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic (3.13.0-119.166) ...
>
> run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-119-generic
>
> run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-119-generic
>
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-119-generic
>
> run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-119-generic
>
> run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/statoverride 3.13.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-119-generic
>
> ***dpkg-statoverride: error: an override for '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-119-generic' already exists; aborting***
>
> run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
>   dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic (--configure):
>
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
>    linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic; however:
>     Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-119-generic is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-virtual:
>    linux-image-extra-virtual depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.119.129); however:
>     Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

#### My solution referred to [this answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258756&page=3) at #28:

`[jeremy@compute]$ su - root
[root@compute]# cp /etc/kernel/postinst.d/statoverride ~/
[root@compute]# sed -i '/dpkg-statoverride/s/$/||:/' /etc/kernel/postinst.d/statoverride`

Hope it is helpful to others who encounter it.